# Leaflet - Is it possible to refresh the L.Icon via setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Im not very knowlagble in Java or JQuery, but I do understand some of it as I used to be a web developer back in the 2000-2010.

What I am using is a Live map mod for a game(7 Days to Die). It is called "Alloc's server fix" which has the live map mod using Leaflet.

I have done some of my own modification to this, mainly just style code and a few image changes. Also added another location overlay.

What I am hoping to accomplish is when a user logs into the game for the offline icon to change to online icon without refreshing/reloading the website(aka F5 key). There are a few things that do auto update like the amount of offline and online players, and game time and day auto updates as well.

I have tried to make this work with the L.icon but with no luck. I have to reload the website for it to change. I believe it has to do with the...

.done(setPlayerMaker) statement locking the icon in but not 100% sure.

here is the code that is being worked with in one file.

maps.js

```
    // player icon
    var playerIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: '/static/leaflet/images/player.png',
        iconRetinaUrl: '/static/leaflet/images/player.png',
        iconSize: [30, 30],
        iconAnchor: [15, 15],
        popupAnchor: [0, -15]
    });
    
    // player offline icon
    var playerOfflineIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: '/static/leaflet/images/player-offline.png',
        iconRetinaUrl: '/static/leaflet/images/player-offline.png',
        iconSize: [30, 30],
        iconAnchor: [15, 15],
        popupAnchor: [0, -15]
    });

    // ===============================================================================================
    // Player markers

    $(".leaflet-popup-pane").on('click.action', '.inventoryButton', function(event) {
        ShowInventoryDialog ($(this).data('steamid'));
    });

    var setPlayerMarkers = function(data) {
        var onlineIds = [];
        updatingMarkers = true;     
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        if (val.online) {
            var marker;
            if (playersMappingList.hasOwnProperty(val.steamid)) {
                marker = playersMappingList[val.steamid].currentPosMarker;
            } else {
                marker = L.marker([val.position.x, val.position.z], {icon: playerIcon}).bindPopup(
                    "Player: " + $("<div>").text(val.name).html() +
                    (HasPermission ("webapi.getplayerinventory") ?
                        "<br/><a class='inventoryButton' data-steamid='"+val.steamid+"'>Show inventory</a>"
                        : "")
                );
                marker.on("move", function ( e ) {
                    if ( this.isPopupOpen () ) {
                        map.flyTo (e.latlng, map.getZoom ());
                    }
                });
                playersMappingList[val.steamid] = { online: !val.online };
            }
            
            if (val.online) {
                onlineIds.push (val.steamid);
            }
            
            oldpos = marker.getLatLng ();
            if ( playersMappingList[val.steamid].online != val.online ) {
                if (playersMappingList[val.steamid].online) {
                    playersOnlineMarkerGroup.removeLayer(marker);
                    playersOfflineMarkerGroup.addLayer(marker);
                } else {
                    playersOfflineMarkerGroup.removeLayer(marker);
                    playersOnlineMarkerGroup.addLayer(marker);
                }
            }
            if ( oldpos.lat != val.position.x || oldpos.lng != val.position.z ) {
                marker.setLatLng([val.position.x, val.position.z]);
                if (val.online) {
                        marker.setOpacity(1.0);
                } else {
                        marker.setOpacity(0.5);
                }
            }

            val.currentPosMarker = marker;
            playersMappingList[val.steamid] = val;
        }
        else
        {
            var marker;
            if (playersMappingList.hasOwnProperty(val.steamid)) {
                marker = playersMappingList[val.steamid].currentPosMarker;
            } else {
                marker = L.marker([val.position.x, val.position.z], {icon: playerOfflineIcon}).bindPopup(
                    "Player: " + $("<div>").text(val.name).html() +
                    (HasPermission ("webapi.getplayerinventory") ?
                        "<br/><a class='inventoryButton' data-steamid='"+val.steamid+"'>Show inventory</a>"
                        : "")
                );
                marker.on("move", function ( e ) {
                    if ( this.isPopupOpen () ) {
                        map.flyTo (e.latlng, map.getZoom ());
                    }
                });
                playersMappingList[val.steamid] = { online: !val.online };
            }
            
            if (val.online) {
                onlineIds.push (val.steamid);
            }
            
            oldpos = marker.getLatLng ();
            if ( playersMappingList[val.steamid].online != val.online ) {
                if (playersMappingList[val.steamid].online) {
                    playersOnlineMarkerGroup.removeLayer(marker);
                    playersOfflineMarkerGroup.addLayer(marker);
                } else {
                    playersOfflineMarkerGroup.removeLayer(marker);
                    playersOnlineMarkerGroup.addLayer(marker);
                }
            }
            if ( oldpos.lat != val.position.x || oldpos.lng != val.position.z ) {
                marker.setLatLng([val.position.x, val.position.z]);
                if (val.online) {
                        marker.setOpacity(1.0);
                } else {
                        marker.setOpacity(0.5);
                }
            }

            val.currentPosMarker = marker;
            playersMappingList[val.steamid] = val;
        }
    });
        
        var online = 0;
        var offline = 0;
        $.each ( playersMappingList, function ( key, val ) {
            if ( val.online && onlineIds.indexOf (key) < 0 ) {
                var marker = val.currentPosMarker;
                playersOnlineMarkerGroup.removeLayer(marker);
                playersOfflineMarkerGroup.addLayer(marker);
                val.online = false;
            }
            if (val.online) {
                online++;
            } else {
                offline++;
            }
        });
        
        updatingMarkers = false;

        $( "#mapControlOnlineCount" ).text( online );
        $( "#mapControlOfflineCount" ).text( offline );
        
    }
        
    var updatePlayerTimeout;
    var playerUpdateCount = -1;
    var updatePlayerEvent = function() {
        playerUpdateCount++;
        
        $.getJSON( "../api/getplayerslocation" + ((playerUpdateCount % 15) == 0 ? "?offline=true" : ""))
        .done(setPlayerMarkers)
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            console.log("Error fetching players list");
        })
        .always(function() {
            updatePlayerTimeout = window.setTimeout(updatePlayerEvent, 2000);
        });
        
        
    }

    tabs.on ("tabbedcontenttabopened", function (event, data) {
        if (data.newTab === "#tab_map") {
            if (HasPermission ("webapi.getplayerslocation")) {
                updatePlayerEvent ();
            }
        } else {
            window.clearTimeout (updatePlayerTimeout);
        }
    });
    
    if (tabs.tabbedContent ("isTabOpen", "tab_map")) {
        if (HasPermission ("webapi.getplayerslocation")) {
            updatePlayerEvent ();
        }
    }
```

I have tried placing setTimeout inside this section...

```
        .always(function() {
            updatePlayerTimeout = window.setTimeout(updatePlayerEvent, 2000);
                        >>>>> window.setTimeout(setPlayerMarker, 2000); <<<<<
        });
```

but it crashes the live map

Comment: Any errors on the browser's console?

Comment: with the code I tried, my console throws this error up:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: setPlayerMarker is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (map.js:372:22)
    at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2:27244)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2:28057)
    at x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4:21843)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4:25897)`